# d3 - csv file header rows in console if a string type

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am using d3 to do data visualization of a csv file.
The csv looks like this:

```
UserId,Reputation,Name,Tags
22656,985942,Jon Skeet,"<c#><google-cloud-platform><google-cloud-datastore><google-authentication>,<msbuild><asp.net-core><mono><.net-core><travis-ci>,<.net><nuget><.net-core><visual-studio-2017><csproj>,<.net><md5>,<c#><wpf><xaml><globalization>,<java><c#><variables><object><reference>,<java><newline>,<c#><.net><debugging><compiler-errors><jit>,<git><git-reset><git-revert><git-clean>,<git>,<java><generics>                                                                                                                             "
```

my index.html looks like this:

```
d3.csv("UsersFavTags.csv", function(data){
console.log(data[0]);
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    data[i].Tags = createTagArray(data[i].Tags)
}
data.forEach(function(d){
    console.log("d: "+d);
    d.Tags = createTagArray(d.Tags);
    d.CountedTags = listOccurence(d.Tags);
    d.Tags = listUnique(d.Tags);
});
console.log(data);
});
```

However, the output in console looks like：

```
{UserId: "22656", Reputation: "985942", Name: "Jon Skeet", "Tags ": "<c#><google-cloud-platform><google-cloud-datastore…                                "}
```

Notice that `Tags` is a string type which is `"Tags "` which makes me not be able to access the value of `Tags`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to `"Tags "` property using `["Tags "]` syntax:

```js
var object = {UserId: "22656", Reputation: "985942", Name: "Jon Skeet", "Tags ": "some string"};

console.log(object["Tags "]);
```

You can also process you `data` and create objects without space at the end:

```js
var data = [
{UserId: "22656", Reputation: "985942", Name: "Jon Skeet", "Tags ": "some string"},
 {UserId: "22657", Reputation: "985943", Name: "Jon Skeet II", "Tags ": "another string"},  
];

data.forEach(function(item){
  item.Tags = item["Tags "]; // store value to the propety without space
  delete item["Tags "]; // delete property with space
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you I makes sense! But do you know what causes my csv files data array having a string type of ‘Tags’?

Comment: I think it is because of in your csv file is a space character after "Tags" word - `"UserId,Reputation,Name,Tags "`

Comment: You could also consider specifying an accessor function which can fix the "Tag " problem as the data is parsed. See here in the docs for more details ; https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md#parse